# Can't access an array within an array; instead, calls affect that number element in every array

Tags: javascript

My `fill()` function is supposed to fill a 2d array of `width` by `height` solely with zeros. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Luxelin/EYXNw/) with the following block of code.

```
var row = new Array(),
    graph = new Array();
var width = 10, height = 10;

function fill(){
    for (var i = 0; i < height; i++){
        for (var k = 0; k < width; k++)
            row[k] = 0;
        graph[i] = row;
    }

    //as expected, it will log 10 arrays, each of 10 zeros
    console.log(graph);

    //should set the 2nd element of the 2nd array to "why?"
    graph[1][1] = "why?";

    //instead, it sets every 2nd element of every array to "why?"
    console.log(graph);
}
fill();
```

I even tried making my 2D array with the following snazzy lines of code:

```
var graph = Array.apply(null, new Array(height)).map(Array.prototype.valueOf,
            Array.apply(null, new Array(width)).map(Number.prototype.valueOf,0));
```

However, `graph[1][1] = "why?"` still causes the second element of every array inside of `graph` to be set to `"why"?`. Why? Am I not allowed to fill arrays like this in JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have filled your graph with 10 references to one row.

to solve this just do it like this:

```
function fill(){
    for (var i = 0; i < height; i++){
        var row = new Array();
        for (var k = 0; k < width; k++) {         
            row[k] = 0;
        }
        graph[i] = row;
    }
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EYXNw/1/

Answer (score 1):

This is because your `row` array is a reference and all the `graph` elements are pointing to that same reference

try something like the following

```
function fill(width, height){           // pass width and height as parameters
    var graph = [];                     // use [] instead of new Array()
    for (var i = 0; i < height; i++){
        var row = [];

        for (var k = 0; k < width; k++)
            row[k] = 0;

        graph[i] = row;
    }

    console.log(graph);                 // prints the original array
    graph[1][1] = "why?";               // set the 2nd element of the 2nd array to "why?"
    console.log(graph);                 // re-print
    return graph;
}


fill(10,10);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

```
var row = new Array(), graph = new Array();
var width = 10, height = 10;

function fill(){
    for (var i = 0; i < height; i++){
        for (var k = 0; k < width; k++){row[k] = 0;}
        graph[i] = row.slice(0);
    }

    console.log(graph);
    graph[1][1] = "why?";
    console.log(graph);
}

fill();
```

**The Problem:**

Your code created an array (`graph`) of references to another array (`row`). You don't want `graph` to contain references to `row`, instead you want `graph` to contain clones of `row`. The above code fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Because you created only one row (array) and assign that same array to every grid location.